# What is the max possible value of KeyEvent.VK_*

Tags: java

I want an array of all VK values so that I can ask if a key is pressed

```
public class Input implements KeyListener{

    boolean[] keyPressed = new boolean [1000];

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        keyPressed[arg0.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        keyPressed[ arg0.getKeyCode() ] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

}
```

Can any one tell me -- What is the max and min VK values?

I dont want Oracle to add new VK values and break my code one day.

Is there a "limits.h" style way I can set it dynamically ?

Comment: I will *eventually* use keyPressed values concurrently... haven't figured out the synchronization yet, Im not quite ready to cross that bridge yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using KeyEvent: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.java

The highest achievable value is (using unicode representation):

```
public static final char CHAR_UNDEFINED   = 0xFFFF;
```

or 65535 in decimal.

This is an unmapped value for an undefined non-unicode character.

The highest defined value for a valid event is:

```
public static final int VK_BEGIN                    = 0xFF58;
```

or 65368 in decimal.

The highest mapped value if you're fine with cutting off a few of the special functions is:

```
public static final int VK_CONTEXT_MENU             = 0x020D;
```

or 525 in decimal.

The lowest defined value is:

```
public static final int VK_UNDEFINED      = 0x0;
```

or 0 in decimal.

Obviously, the true max and true min are not achievable from the keyboard, but they serve as limits reasonable hard-coded. `VK_CANCEL` comes in at 0x03 for potentially the lowest actual usable mapped value.

Comment: hmm, a full 16 bits of VK_ values seem like overkill for me but thanks for the info its very helpful - Ill have to do an init process that determines the max value of all the keys I actually have mapped and go from there I think.

Comment: DO you know if Im garunteed to have all positive VK_ values anywhere ?

Comment: Are there negative unicode values? Serious question.

Comment: Also, I looked at it some more. The VK_BEGIN value is super-high. You could potentially get away with 0x020D if all the extra fancy options aren't of interest.